# How to navigate to another method or class while reading code at Github.com

Tags: java, github

I am reading some JDK code in github , for example:
[image]

and I would like to read the source code of referenced methods there,
for example `StrictMatch.floor(a)`

In Eclipse, I would do this by typing CTRL + mouse click on the method.

is there a way to do this in github ?

is there any other site where I can navigate the JDK code and have these features ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gunnar Morling](https://twitter.com/gunnarmorling)  (Open source software engineer @ Red Hat and Java Champion) just [tweeted](https://twitter.com/gunnarmorling/status/1248903547539918848):

> Woot, looks like code navigation is rolled out for #Java on @github!
>
> Still needs a bit more fine-tuning (e.g. show method name instead of those pesky Override annotations), but that feature is a welcomed addition for sure.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EVT-nN8WoAI_AjQ?format=jpg&name=4096x4096]

This was announced in "[Code navigation is now available for all CodeQL and Java repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-10-code-navigation-is-now-available-for-all-codeql-and-java-repositories/) "

> Jump to definition and find all references are now available for all CodeQL and Java repositories on GitHub.
>
> When viewing a CodeQL or Java file on github.com, clicking on a function or method name exposes a code navigation card with links to all of its definitions and references within the same repository.
>
> We use the [semantic library](https://github.com/github/semantic) to find definitions and call sites in your code.

Comment: yeah!!, it is true, at least worked for the Math class, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe GitHub has this feature but you could clone the repository and look at it with eclipse(or any other IDE).

Comment: yes, thanks, the idea is not to clone, easy access even if I change of computer

Comment: repl.it does have GitHub integration and find reference so that's probably your best bet.

Comment: but it is not  what I was looking for, it is the same, I have to clone, besides has a limit of 100 mb, and then I have to pay. I was looking for something like github, the code is there and I can navigate it.

Comment: @Leo If your issue with cloning is changing computers, consider cloning onto a USB drive.

Comment: @Leo It looks like GitHub does have code navigation: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/navigating-code-on-github. However, Java is not supported, though [maybe that will change in the future](https://github.com/github/semantic#language-support). In [this article](https://medium.com/@droidchef/how-to-navigate-through-your-java-projects-on-github-like-a-boss-488a37e16310) the author claims to have made a intra-project navigator, though [the project](https://github.com/droidchef/hops) looks dead (hasn't been updated in a few years, despite open issues and PRs).

Comment: @Leo Here's another [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sourcegraph/dgjhfomjieaadpoljlnidmbgkdffpack?hl=en). It apparently works via https://about.sourcegraph.com/. Note I haven't tried any of these things, so I don't know how easy it is to set up or if they even work.